# s3 backup strategy: versioning vs sync to another s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, versioning

I just want to know the best strategy for backup of the files stored on s3 bucket. I can think of 2 options - enabling versioning and (periodically e.g. once a day) syncing to new s3 bucket. The files are created by Athena CTAS queries every day and the file names are randomly generated. If I delete the files by accident, I need to restore it from the backup. Some advantages of having another s3 bucket is that it protects from accidental delete of the original s3 bucket itself and another one is easy restore process of the deleted file(s). On another hand, versioning looks simple and most preferred. I could not find my articles talking about the pros and cons of these 2 approaches and hence this question/debate. I just want to know the pros and cons of each approach.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically do not need to "backup" Amazon S3 objects because they are replicated in multiple data centers. However, as yu point out you might want a method to handle "accidental deletion".

One option is to **prevent deletion by using Object Locking or a Bucket Policy**. If people aren't permitted to delete objects, then there is no need for a backup.

Of the two options you present, **Versioning is a better option** because you are not duplicating objects. This means that you are not paying twice for storage. It is also simpler because there is no need to configure replication.

Buckets cannot be deleted unless they are empty.